# pyspark select/filter statement both not working

Tags: select, pyspark, filter

I am learning the pyspark with the book "Spark: The Definitive Guide". I am learning the window function section.My code is:

```
**dfWithDate.where("CustomerId IS NOT NULL").orderBy("CustomerId").select(col("CustomerId"),col("date"),col("Quantity"),purchaseRank.alias("quantityRank"),purchaseDenseRank.alias("quantityDenseRank"),maxPurchaseQuantity.alias("maxPurchaseQuantity")).show()**
```

I received an error:

[image]

I also try:

```
df2=dfWithDate.filter(" CustomerId IS NOT NULL").orderBy("CustomerId").show()
```

I received the same type of error. I want to know what causes this reason and the way to fix it.

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not about select/filter. It's pretty clear in the exception you got

> Fail to parse '6/12/2011 13:001 in the new parser. You can set spark.sal. legacy. timeParserpolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string